# xcodebuild error: "requested but didn't find extension point with identifier ..."

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I'm using `Xcode 13.3.1`.

I'm trying to build a flutter application in Android Studio. It failed with the following error. To make it dead simple I tried just running `xcodebuild` which produced the same error as in Android Studio:

```
 .oh-my-zsh git:(master) xcodebuild
2022-04-21 19:45:25.858 xcodebuild[32450:312401] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
2022-04-21 19:45:25.859 xcodebuild[32450:312401] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild

User defaults from command line:
    IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

xcodebuild: error: The directory /Users/salahuddin/.oh-my-zsh does not contain an Xcode project.
```

Any idea what causes this error and how to fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Please help me with dependencies problem in Flutter. Says build failed because of something related to Apple Watch but I am not using Apple Watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72270890/please-help-me-with-dependencies-problem-in-flutter-says-build-failed-because-o)

Answer (score 6):

Please refer to the message, you can find out solution.
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/703233

SOLUTION (for me):

I had to first find the software update manually:

softwareupdate --list

This provided me with the following output:

Finding available software
Software Update found the following new or updated software:

- Label: Command Line Tools for Xcode-13.3
  Title: Command Line Tools for Xcode, Version: 13.3, Size: 718145KiB, Recommended: YES,
  I then ran:

softwareupdate -i "Command Line Tools for Xcode-13.3"

(NOTE: You pass the "Label:" output as the string as yours could be different.

Answer (score 3):

This command worked out for me: `softwareupdate -d -a`.

Reference: https://huckfinnsmoneytree.com/how-to-download-macos-updates-using-the-terminal/

Comment: when I run this command I got `no new updates available`

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem when updating the project with Flutter 3. After several attempts, **the below solution worked for me**.

I have deleted the `podfile.lock` file inside the `ios` folder and then run the below commands.

1. `flutter pub upgrade`
2. `flutter pub get`
3. `cd ios`
4. `pod repo update` > Actually, this was an error for me but ignored it
5. `pod install`

Also please make sure you are using the latest `MacOS` and `Xcode`.
I hope this will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to install the Xcode command line tools, which you can do by executing the following command in Terminal:
`xcode-select --install`

Comment: I tried running this command -> `xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates`. Also tried `softwareupdate --install` but nothing was installed.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Completely turn off Bluetooth.

in ios/ folder of your project, change Podfile to
`platform :ios, '12.0'`

Run `pod deintegrate` in Terminal inside the ios/ folder of your project.

Run `pod install --repo-update` in your ios/ folder

https://solveforums.msomimaktaba.com/threads/solved-flutter-for-ios-run-build-but-not-archive.699314/

Comment: I don't think this solution has anything to do with the author's question.

Answer (score 0):

The error mentions that there's no iOS project to be found on the directory.

```
xcodebuild: error: The directory /Users/salahuddin/.oh-my-zsh does not contain an Xcode project.
```

You'd need to navigate to the iOS build of your Flutter project on your terminal with `cd ios` and run `xcodebuild` there.

Answer (score 0):

multiple xcode.app you need to remove.(Download folder)

1. XCode-> Preferences-> Locations -> Command Line Tools
2. Check it shows multiple entries for same xcode version.
3. Delete xCode.app other than Application folder.
4. quit and restart xcode and terminal.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I was using Xcode 13.4. I downloaded Xcode 13.3 from [here](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=xcode) and everything started working again.

I was encountering this issue on a self-hosted GitHub runner so in order for the fix above to work, I needed to:

1. Uninstall the Xcode 13.4
2. Remove the GitHub runner
3. Install Xcode 13.3
4. Re-add the GitHub runner

Answer (score 0):

Try This.
Remove any command line tools:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Reinstall them:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Tell the system to use them:

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

If still not working, try that:

- In Xcode > Preferences > Locations tab
- Simply select the right toolset.