# Fixing a dependencies problem in Flutter. Says build failed because of something related to Apple Watch but I am not using Apple Watch

Tags: flutter, dart, build, dependencies, pubspec

I am running into a problem when trying to build my Flutter app.  I am using VS Code and the latest versions of Flutter and Dart.  I think I have a problem with dependencies, but not sure.  I have the following dependencies in my pubspec.yaml file:

```
  http: ^0.13.4
  youtube_player_flutter: ^8.0.0
  percent_indicator: ^3.4.0
  endless: ^1.6.0
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.6.1
  transparent_image:
  accordion: ^2.2.3
  like_button: ^2.0.4
  easy_firebase_auth: ^3.2.0
  flutter_inappwebview: ^5.4.3+7
  webview_flutter: ^3.0.4
  firebase_core: ^1.6.0
  cloud_firestore: ^2.5.1
  url_launcher: ^6.1.2
  geocoding: ^2.0.4
  sign_in_with_apple: ^3.3.0
```

I run into a problem when I do a flutter build.  I get the following error messages:

```
2022-05-17 01:32:19.580 xcodebuild[26038:192413] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier
Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of
plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
2022-05-17 01:32:19.580 xcodebuild[26038:192413] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier
Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension
Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳

Writing result bundle at path:
    /var/folders/xp/fl30w5315b33hw_npc3wykb40000gn/T/flutter_tools.vcek1g/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirjbPPUe/temporary_
    xcresult_bundle

/Users/gregoryew/flutter_apps/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geocoding-2.0.4/ios/Classes/Extensions/CL
PlacemarkExtensions.m:22:18: warning: 'addressDictionary' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 11.0 - Use
@properties [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        if (self.addressDictionary != nil) {
                 ^
In module 'CoreLocation' imported from
/Users/gregoryew/flutter_apps/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geocoding-2.0.4/ios/Classes/Extensions/CL
PlacemarkExtensions.h:10:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.5.sdk/System/Libr
ary/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/Headers/CLPlacemark.h:73:63: note: 'addressDictionary' has been explicitly
marked deprecated here
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy, nullable) NSDictionary *addressDictionary API_DEPRECATED("Use @properties",
macos(10.8, 10.13), ios(5.0, 11.0), watchos(1.0, 4.0));
                                                              ^
/Users/gregoryew/flutter_apps/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geocoding-2.0.4/ios/Classes/Extensions/CL
PlacemarkExtensions.m:23:29: warning: 'addressDictionary' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 11.0 - Use
@properties [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
            street = [[self addressDictionary] objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStreetKey];
                            ^
In module 'CoreLocation' imported from
/Users/gregoryew/flutter_apps/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geocoding-2.0.4/ios/Classes/Extensions/CL
PlacemarkExtensions.h:10:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.5.sdk/System/Libr
ary/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/Headers/CLPlacemark.h:73:63: note: property 'addressDictionary' is declared
deprecated here
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy, nullable) NSDictionary *addressDictionary API_DEPRECATED("Use @properties",
macos(10.8, 10.13), ios(5.0, 11.0), watchos(1.0, 4.0));
                                                              ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.5.sdk/System/Libr
ary/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/Headers/CLPlacemark.h:73:63: note: 'addressDictionary' has been explicitly
marked deprecated here
/Users/gregoryew/flutter_apps/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geocoding-2.0.4/ios/Classes/Extensions/CL
PlacemarkExtensions.m:23:73: warning: 'kABPersonAddressStreetKey' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - use
CNPostalAddress.street [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
            street = [[self addressDictionary] objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStreetKey];
                                                                        ^
In module 'AddressBook' imported from
/Users/gregoryew/flutter_apps/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geocoding-2.0.4/ios/Classes/Extensions/CL
PlacemarkExtensions.m:8:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.5.sdk/System/Libr
ary/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/Headers/ABPerson.h:113:29: note: 'kABPersonAddressStreetKey' has been
explicitly marked deprecated here
AB_EXTERN const CFStringRef kABPersonAddressStreetKey AB_DEPRECATED("use CNPostalAddress.street");
                            ^
3 warnings generated.
/Users/gregoryew/flutter_apps/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.4.3+7/ios/Classes/
Types/URLCredential.swift:14:25: warning: comparing non-optional value of type '[Any]' to 'nil' always returns
true
        if certificates != nil {
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~
/Users/gregoryew/flutter_apps/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.4.3+7/ios/Classes/
InAppBrowser/InAppBrowserWebViewController.swift:561:13: warning: setter for 'statusBarStyle' was deprecated in
iOS 9.0: Use -[UIViewController preferredStatusBarStyle]
            UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle(rawValue: previousStatusBarStyle)!
            ^
/Users/gregoryew/flutter_apps/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.4.3+7/ios/Classes/
Util.swift:86:25: warning: 'spotlightSuggestion' was deprecated in iOS 10.0: renamed to
'WKDataDetectorTypes.lookupSuggestion'
                return .spotlightSuggestion
                        ^
/Users/gregoryew/flutter_apps/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.4.3+7/ios/Classes/
Util.swift:86:25: note: use 'WKDataDetectorTypes.lookupSuggestion' instead
                return .spotlightSuggestion
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                        WKDataDetectorTypes.lookupSuggestion
/Users/gregoryew/flutter_apps/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.4.3+7/ios/Classes/
Util.swift:121:31: warning: 'spotlightSuggestion' was deprecated in iOS 10.0: renamed to
'WKDataDetectorTypes.lookupSuggestion'
            if type.contains(.spotlightSuggestion) {
                              ^
/Users/gregoryew/flutter_apps/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.4.3+7/ios/Classes/
Util.swift:121:31: note: use 'WKDataDetectorTypes.lookupSuggestion' instead
            if type.contains(.spotlightSuggestion) {
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                              WKDataDetectorTypes.lookupSuggestion
/Users/gregoryew/flutter_apps/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.4.3+7/ios/Classes/
Util.swift:216:21: warning: immutable value 'j' was never used; consider replacing with '_' or removing it
                for j in ipv6.count...8 {
                    ^
                    _
/* com.apple.ibtool.document.warnings */
/Users/gregoryew/flutter_apps/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.4.3+7/ios/Storyboa
rds/WebView.storyboard:global: warning: This file is set to build for a version older than the deployment target.
Functionality may be limited. [9]
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:25:6: Error: Error when reading
'../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/add_event.g.dart': No such file or directory
part 'animated_icons/data/add_event.g.dart';
     ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:26:6: Error: Error when reading
'../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/arrow_menu.g.dart': No such file or directory
part 'animated_icons/data/arrow_menu.g.dart';
     ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:27:6: Error: Error when reading
'../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/close_menu.g.dart': No such file or directory
part 'animated_icons/data/close_menu.g.dart';
     ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:28:6: Error: Error when reading
'../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/ellipsis_search.g.dart': No such file or
directory
part 'animated_icons/data/ellipsis_search.g.dart';
     ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:29:6: Error: Error when reading
'../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/event_add.g.dart': No such file or directory
part 'animated_icons/data/event_add.g.dart';
     ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:30:6: Error: Error when reading
'../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/home_menu.g.dart': No such file or directory
part 'animated_icons/data/home_menu.g.dart';
     ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:31:6: Error: Error when reading
'../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/list_view.g.dart': No such file or directory
part 'animated_icons/data/list_view.g.dart';
     ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:32:6: Error: Error when reading
'../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/menu_arrow.g.dart': No such file or directory
part 'animated_icons/data/menu_arrow.g.dart';
     ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:33:6: Error: Error when reading
'../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/menu_close.g.dart': No such file or directory
part 'animated_icons/data/menu_close.g.dart';
     ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:34:6: Error: Error when reading
'../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/menu_home.g.dart': No such file or directory
part 'animated_icons/data/menu_home.g.dart';
     ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:35:6: Error: Error when reading
'../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/pause_play.g.dart': No such file or directory
part 'animated_icons/data/pause_play.g.dart';
     ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:36:6: Error: Error when reading
'../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/play_pause.g.dart': No such file or directory
part 'animated_icons/data/play_pause.g.dart';
     ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:37:6: Error: Error when reading
'../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/search_ellipsis.g.dart': No such file or
directory
part 'animated_icons/data/search_ellipsis.g.dart';
     ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:38:6: Error: Error when reading
'../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/view_list.g.dart': No such file or directory
part 'animated_icons/data/view_list.g.dart';
     ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:25:6: Error: Can't use
'../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/add_event.g.dart' as a part, because it has
no 'part of' declaration.
part 'animated_icons/data/add_event.g.dart';
     ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:26:6: Error: Can't use
'../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/arrow_menu.g.dart' as a part, because it has
no 'part of' declaration.
part 'animated_icons/data/arrow_menu.g.dart';
     ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:27:6: Error: Can't use
'../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/close_menu.g.dart' as a part, because it has
no 'part of' declaration.
part 'animated_icons/data/close_menu.g.dart';
     ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:28:6: Error: Can't use
'../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/ellipsis_search.g.dart' as a part, because it
has no 'part of' declaration.
part 'animated_icons/data/ellipsis_search.g.dart';
     ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:29:6: Error: Can't use
'../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/event_add.g.dart' as a part, because it has
no 'part of' declaration.
part 'animated_icons/data/event_add.g.dart';
     ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:30:6: Error: Can't use
'../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/home_menu.g.dart' as a part, because it has
no 'part of' declaration.
part 'animated_icons/data/home_menu.g.dart';
     ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:31:6: Error: Can't use
'../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/list_view.g.dart' as a part, because it has
no 'part of' declaration.
part 'animated_icons/data/list_view.g.dart';
     ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:32:6: Error: Can't use
'../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/menu_arrow.g.dart' as a part, because it has
no 'part of' declaration.
part 'animated_icons/data/menu_arrow.g.dart';
     ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:33:6: Error: Can't use
'../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/menu_close.g.dart' as a part, because it has
no 'part of' declaration.
part 'animated_icons/data/menu_close.g.dart';
     ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:34:6: Error: Can't use
'../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/menu_home.g.dart' as a part, because it has
no 'part of' declaration.
part 'animated_icons/data/menu_home.g.dart';
     ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:35:6: Error: Can't use
'../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/pause_play.g.dart' as a part, because it has
no 'part of' declaration.
part 'animated_icons/data/pause_play.g.dart';
     ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:36:6: Error: Can't use
'../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/play_pause.g.dart' as a part, because it has
no 'part of' declaration.
part 'animated_icons/data/play_pause.g.dart';
     ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:37:6: Error: Can't use
'../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/search_ellipsis.g.dart' as a part, because it
has no 'part of' declaration.
part 'animated_icons/data/search_ellipsis.g.dart';
     ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:38:6: Error: Can't use
'../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/data/view_list.g.dart' as a part, because it has
no 'part of' declaration.
part 'animated_icons/data/view_list.g.dart';
     ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/animated_icons_data.dart:19:45: Error: Undefined
name '_$add_event'.
  static const AnimatedIconData add_event = _$add_event;
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/animated_icons_data.dart:22:46: Error: Undefined
name '_$arrow_menu'.
  static const AnimatedIconData arrow_menu = _$arrow_menu;
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/animated_icons_data.dart:25:46: Error: Undefined
name '_$close_menu'.
  static const AnimatedIconData close_menu = _$close_menu;
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/animated_icons_data.dart:28:51: Error: Undefined
name '_$ellipsis_search'.
  static const AnimatedIconData ellipsis_search = _$ellipsis_search;
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/animated_icons_data.dart:31:45: Error: Undefined
name '_$event_add'.
  static const AnimatedIconData event_add = _$event_add;
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/animated_icons_data.dart:34:45: Error: Undefined
name '_$home_menu'.
  static const AnimatedIconData home_menu = _$home_menu;
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/animated_icons_data.dart:37:45: Error: Undefined
name '_$list_view'.
  static const AnimatedIconData list_view = _$list_view;
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/animated_icons_data.dart:40:46: Error: Undefined
name '_$menu_arrow'.
  static const AnimatedIconData menu_arrow = _$menu_arrow;
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/animated_icons_data.dart:43:46: Error: Undefined
name '_$menu_close'.
  static const AnimatedIconData menu_close = _$menu_close;
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/animated_icons_data.dart:46:45: Error: Undefined
name '_$menu_home'.
  static const AnimatedIconData menu_home = _$menu_home;
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/animated_icons_data.dart:49:46: Error: Undefined
name '_$pause_play'.
  static const AnimatedIconData pause_play = _$pause_play;
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/animated_icons_data.dart:52:46: Error: Undefined
name '_$play_pause'.
  static const AnimatedIconData play_pause = _$play_pause;
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/animated_icons_data.dart:55:51: Error: Undefined
name '_$search_ellipsis'.
  static const AnimatedIconData search_ellipsis = _$search_ellipsis;
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons/animated_icons_data.dart:58:45: Error: Undefined
name '_$view_list'.
  static const AnimatedIconData view_list = _$view_list;
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:58:10: Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Widget' doesn't allow null.
 - 'Widget' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart'
 ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
         ^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-5.0.0/lib/src/inherited_provider.dart:391:26: Warning:
Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart'
 ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
        SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                         ^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/percent_indicator-3.4.0/lib/linear_percent_indicator.dart:156:20:
Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart'
 ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                   ^
Failed to package /Users/gregoryew/flutter_apps/FelineFinder/feline_finder.
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
note: Using new build system
note: Planning
note: Build preparation complete
note: Building targets in dependency order
/Users/gregoryew/flutter_apps/FelineFinder/feline_finder/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment
target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
15.5.99. (in target 'leveldb-library' from project 'Pods')
/Users/gregoryew/flutter_apps/FelineFinder/feline_finder/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment
target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
15.5.99. (in target 'OrderedSet' from project 'Pods')
/Users/gregoryew/flutter_apps/FelineFinder/feline_finder/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment
target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
15.5.99. (in target 'AppAuth' from project 'Pods')
/Users/gregoryew/flutter_apps/FelineFinder/feline_finder/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment
target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
15.5.99. (in target 'GoogleSignIn' from project 'Pods')

Result bundle written to path:
    /var/folders/xp/fl30w5315b33hw_npc3wykb40000gn/T/flutter_tools.vcek1g/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirjbPPUe/temporary_
    xcresult_bundle


Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

Error launching application on iPhone.
```

I tried deleting `*.g.dart` and running all the solutions I could find for similar problems but nothing works.  It all seemed to occur after I added the following to my `info.plist` but not sure if this is related or not.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>comgooglemaps</string>
</array>
```

Also getting the following when I do a flutter run in vs code's output window but not sure if it is related:

```
Running "flutter pub get" in example...                         
Null check operator used on a null value
package:pub/src/entrypoint.dart 157:60                           Entrypoint.lockFilePath
package:pub/src/entrypoint.dart 100:21                           Entrypoint._loadLockFile
package:pub/src/entrypoint.dart 97:42                            Entrypoint.lockFile
package:pub/src/entrypoint.dart 286:21                           Entrypoint.acquireDependencies.<fn>
package:pub/src/entrypoint.dart 280:68                           Entrypoint.acquireDependencies.<fn>
package:pub/src/log.dart 428:18                                  progress
package:pub/src/entrypoint.dart 280:26                           Entrypoint.acquireDependencies
package:pub/src/command/get.dart 52:22                           GetCommand.runProtected
package:pub/src/command.dart 183:45                              PubCommand.run.<fn>
package:pub/src/command.dart 183:33                              PubCommand.run.<fn>
dart:async                                                       new Future.sync
package:pub/src/utils.dart 109:12                                captureErrors.wrappedCallback
dart:async                                                       runZonedGuarded
package:pub/src/utils.dart 126:5                                 captureErrors
package:pub/src/command.dart 183:13                              PubCommand.run
package:args/command_runner.dart 209:27                          CommandRunner.runCommand
package:pub/src/command_runner.dart 174:24                       PubCommandRunner.runCommand
package:pub/src/command_runner.dart 159:20                       PubCommandRunner.run
package:dartdev/dartdev.dart 45:56                               runDartdev
/opt/s/w/ir/cache/builder/sdk/pkg/dartdev/bin/dartdev.dart 11:9  main
This is an unexpected error. The full log and other details are collected in:

    /Users/gregoryew/flutter_apps/flutter/.pub-cache/log/pub_log.txt

Consider creating an issue on https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/new
and attaching the relevant parts of that log file.
.
pub get failed (255; .)
exit code 255
```

I am pretty new to Flutter & Dart.  What can I try?

Comment: **Update**:  I tried to make a new project and copy all the files over there but that did not work.  I am stuck on what I am supposed to do to get over this error.  Also, I opened an issue on the dart GitHub but so far there has been no answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have similar error and after many tries I solved in this way:

- Update MacOS
- Update Xcode and command lines tools
- Run `flutter pub upgrade`, `flutter pub get` in the project folder
- Delete podfile.lock in ios folder of the project
- Run `cd ios`, `pod repo update`, `pod install` in the project folder

Comment: Thanks, Alegos27!!!  I just got it working now as well.  What I had to do was flutter downgrade and then flutter upgrade back again.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the universal fix for this issue. In almost all cases you run the above commands. It must have something to do that the iPhone is connected to the apple watch.

Comment: adding `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions` to the 3rd step above first then running everything else worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Delete Runner.xcworkspace,Podfile.lock

then follow these steps

[Error when trying to run my Flutter App with my m1 mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68168869/error-when-trying-to-run-my-flutter-app-with-my-m1-mac)

Comment: This should have been a comment.